# Custom page for filtering posts, WordPress is going 404 for any year other than the current year in the URL (&year=)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page I am calling `news/`. It is not set as the blog page and nor do I want it to be the blog page. I just want several dropdowns with a filter button that will display posts with a pagination that match the dropdown criteria, otherwise display all posts in the list. Here is the code:

```
get_header(); 

$category = $_GET['category'] ?? '';
$tag = $_GET['tag'] ?? '';
$year = isset($_GET['year']) ? intval($_GET['year']) : 0;

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'category_name'  => $category,
    'tag'            => $tag,
);

if ($year) {
    $args['date_query'] = array(
        'year' => $year,
    );
}

$query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php
$categories = get_categories(array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
));

$tags = get_tags(array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
));

$years = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date)
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_status = 'publish'
    ORDER BY post_date DESC
");

var_dump($years);
var_dump($year);

?>
<form action="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" method="get">
    <label for="category">Select a category:</label>
    <select name="category" id="category">
        <option value="">All Articles</option>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($category->slug); ?>" <?php selected(isset($_GET['category']) && $_GET['category'] === $category->slug); ?>>
                <?php echo esc_html($category->name); ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <label for="tag">Select a tag:</label>
    <select name="tag" id="tag">
        <option value="">Tags</option>
        <?php foreach ($tags as $tag) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($tag->slug); ?>" <?php selected(isset($_GET['tag']) && $_GET['tag'] === $tag->slug); ?>>
                <?php echo esc_html($tag->name); ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
        <label for="year">Select a year:</label>
    <select name="year" id="year">
        <option value="">All Years</option>
        <?php foreach ($years as $archive_year) : ?>
                    <?php var_dump($years); ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($archive_year); ?>" <?php selected(isset($_GET['year']) && $_GET['year'] === $archive_year); ?>>
                <?php echo esc_html($archive_year); ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Filter">
</form>


<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <!-- Display your post content here -->
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class="post-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- Add pagination links -->
    <?php
    global $wp_query;
    $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if ($total_pages > 1) {
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
        echo '<div class="pagination">';
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base'      => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format'    => 'page/%#%',
            'current'   => $current_page,
            'total'     => $total_pages,
            'prev_text' => '&laquo;',
            'next_text' => '&raquo;',
        ));
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <p>No posts found</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    


<?php
get_footer();
```

The issue is that for any url, it is working fine as long as the URL is:
`https://site/news/?category=&year=2023`
Or
`https://site/news/?category=&year=`
or any URL without the year parameter
The moment you put in:
`https://site/news/?category=&year=2022` or any other year, 2022, 2021, 2020 it goes to a 404 page.

If I put a year in via hard code in the above code, but don't have 2022, 2021, 2020 in the url, it will filter fine.

I am assuming this is an issue with the Settings > Permalinks in my WordPress, but I am not understanding how to set it up. Currently it looks like this:

Custom Structure: /%category%/%postname%/

I noticed if I just selected the first option, other years would redirect to the traditional wordpress search and not my custom `news/` filter page. I do not want this. I don't care about the traditional WordPress search posts page/functions. I just want all years to filter in place on my custom news page along with the other criteria.

Comment: @ChrisHaas this worked! I did not notice this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain query string parameters, including `year`, are considered "reserved" by WordPress, and using them might kick in undefined behavior, including possibly a 404 page. Unfortunately, the only location that I can find that documents this is on the [`register_taxonomy`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#reserved-terms) page, which is very much not obvious because the problem is system-wide, and not just related to taxonomy names.

> Avoiding the following reserved terms is particularly important if you are passing the term through the $_GET or $_POST array. Doing so can cause WordPress to respond with a 404 error without any other hint or explanation.

The fast and easy solution to this is to just pick a different parameter for the year, such as `y`. The longer and more complicated solution is to possibly hook into [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/), however I think that's too late and the query will already be setup, so instead you might have to have a dedicated [rewrite rule](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) instead.

If anyone else stumbles on this some day and you have a need for year, month and day, so you decide to use `y`, `m` and `d` for consistency, unfortunately `m` is also reserved, however `month` isn't.